# Python: Check if datetime is in correct format

Tags: python, csv

I am reading in a csv file, I'm trying to check if the date-time is in the correct format before displaying it. The date looks like this in the csv file is: 2005-04-05T04:00:01+00:00

I can only get as far as after the plus sign. I might be missing something when i read the documentation.

```
if datetime.datetime.strptime('2005-04-05T04:00:01+00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f'):
            print("This works, but not what i want")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to test if the timestamp is in the correct format?  Or are you trying to reformat the string?

Comment: Trying to test if it's the correct format.

Comment: In that case, see my answer below.  That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could test against a regular expression.   This regex below does the trick.

```
import re

date = '2005-04-05T04:00:01+00'
r = re.compile('^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{2}')
if r.match(date) is not None:
   print 'matches'
```

Comment: This checks for the right format but it doesn't check for valid dates.

Answer (score 3):

Trying using dateutil:

```
import dateutil.parser

dateutil.parser.parse('2005-04-05T04:00:01+00:00')
```